# Spring Batch Tables Purging

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

What is the best way to purge Spring Tables?

Does Spring provides any APIS for **purging**? or, Do We need to execute delete statements on all Spring Batch Tables?

Answer (score 4):

I created  a procedure to clean Up data before a date given.

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS purgeJobsTableBefore 
$$

CREATE PROCEDURE purgeJobsTableBefore (
    IN createTime VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN

DELETE
FROM
   batch_job_execution_context 
WHERE
   JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN 
   (
      SELECT
         JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
      FROM
         batch_job_execution 
      WHERE
         create_time <= createTime
   );

DELETE
FROM
   batch_job_execution_params 
WHERE
   JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN 
   (
      SELECT
         JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
      FROM
         batch_job_execution 
      WHERE
         create_time <= createTime
   );

DELETE
FROM
   batch_step_execution_context 
WHERE
   step_execution_id IN 
   (
      SELECT
         step_execution_id 
      FROM
         batch_step_execution 
      WHERE
         JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN 
         (
            SELECT
               JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
            FROM
               batch_job_execution 
            WHERE
               create_time <= createTime
         )
   );

DELETE
FROM
   batch_step_execution 
WHERE
   JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN 
   (
      SELECT
         JOB_EXECUTION_ID 
      FROM
         batch_job_execution 
      WHERE
         create_time <= createTime
   );

DELETE
FROM
   batch_job_execution 
WHERE
   create_time <= createTime;

DELETE
FROM
   batch_job_instance 
WHERE
   JOB_INSTANCE_ID < (
   SELECT
      MIN(JOB_INSTANCE_ID) 
   FROM
      batch_job_execution 
   WHERE
      create_time >= createTime);

END;
$$
```

You just have to call the procedure with a date to clear up data before that date.

```
CALL purgeJobsTableBefore('2020-05-22');
```

Answer (score 2):

i have been struggling with this for a ling time but, there is no standard implementation for this.

Then i came up with a my own stored procedure ,

I have created my own variable - for clearing last 6 months data AGO_SIX_MONTH_DATE

You can use your own value.

The solution is at below link  -

[Spring Batch Meta-Data tables Purging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945203/spring-batch-meta-data-tables-purging/51424692)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to set batch.data.source.init=true in your properties this would mean that you drop and re-create the tables on each new deployment..

Answer (score 1):

So far yes, you need to delete data by yourself. Spring Batch tables usually contain important data - so it's unusually that somebody wants to delete it from production system.

Comment: Thanks ,On git hub I see below one https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javaetmoi/core/batch/tasklet/RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet.java  ...Looks like RemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet is doing purge kind of activity, Any Idea about this?

Comment: Yes, it's not spring framework's code, but you can use it to purge your data.

Answer (score 0):

After a long research I've discover a clean way.

1. Using [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.javaetmoi.core/spring-batch-toolkit) library. The source code is public on github where you can see an example of use reading [this test](https://github.com/arey/spring-batch-toolkit/blob/master/src/test/java/com/javaetmoi/core/batch/tasklet/TestRemoveSpringBatchHistoryTasklet.java).
2. Manually: First be sure that your server is not running jobs. Then if you are using sql server you can run the [Official drop schema script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql) in your DB here. Or if you are using other db you can find an script for you [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core).Then you can recreate your schema in two ways:

   1. Using official script to do it manually. Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql) if you are using sql server or search your best option [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core).
   2. Turning on `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property to `always`. Then restart your server to automatic spring batch schema recreation.

> spring.batch.initialize-schema=always