# Strategy to clean Spring Batch tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-batch

Spring Batch framework defines [several `BATCH_` prefixed tables](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql).

They leave index definitions to end-users and curtain queries can't avoid full scan by design. So performance requires slimming of tables.

We don't need to keep historical `BATCH_*` data for more than 1 week.

I can't come up with rejection strategy for Postgres that doesn't require all our batch processes stopping.

If it is easy to stop Batch jobs then I can `truncate` or `drop` `BATCH_*` tables. This require coordination between DB maintenance and Batch job maintenance.

I think about `delete` data based on `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.CREATE_TIME < current_date - 7` with corresponding joins. Special care should be taken to Postgres to reclaim used memory via `vacuum`. As I understand it is impossible to reclaim table storage without `vacuum full` but `full` locks `BATCH_` tables. This blocks Batch processes...

**UPDATE** My current cleanup plan is (with performance stats in units + seconds):

```
-- 2.1M  43s
-- Quick cleanup of majority of records.
DELETE FROM batch_step_execution_context bsec
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM batch_step_execution bse
    WHERE bse.start_time < current_date - 22 and bsec.step_execution_id = bse.step_execution_id);
-- 2.5s
vacuum batch_step_execution_context;

-- 2.1M  40s
-- Quick cleanup of majority of records.
DELETE FROM batch_step_execution bse
WHERE bse.start_time < current_date - 22;
-- 59s
vacuum batch_step_execution;

-- 0  1.4s
-- Full cleanup.
DELETE FROM batch_step_execution_context bsec
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM batch_step_execution bse
    join batch_job_execution bje on bje.job_execution_id = bse.job_execution_id
    WHERE bje.start_time < current_date - 22 and bsec.step_execution_id = bse.step_execution_id);

-- 0  1.2s
-- Full cleanup.
DELETE FROM batch_step_execution bse
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM batch_job_execution bje
    WHERE bje.start_time < current_date - 22 and bje.job_execution_id = bse.job_execution_id);

-- 122k  .49s
DELETE FROM batch_job_execution_params bjep
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM batch_job_execution bje
    WHERE bje.start_time < current_date - 22 and bje.job_execution_id = bjep.job_execution_id);
-- 1.2s
vacuum batch_job_execution_params;

-- 61k  .31s
DELETE FROM batch_job_execution_context bjec
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM batch_job_execution bje
    WHERE bje.start_time < current_date - 22 and bje.job_execution_id = bjec.job_execution_id);
-- .68s
vacuum batch_job_execution_context;

-- 61k  4.4s
DELETE FROM batch_job_execution bje
WHERE bje.start_time < current_date - 22;
-- .21s
vacuum batch_job_execution;

-- 61k  1.1s
DELETE FROM batch_job_instance bji
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM batch_job_execution bje WHERE bje.job_instance_id = bji.job_instance_id);
-- .33s
vacuum batch_job_instance;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233217/spring-batch-tables-purging. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1747?focusedCommentId=66226&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-66226

Answer (score 1):

may be duplicate ....  posting the same answer again , hope this helps

i have been struggling with this for a ling time but, there is no standard implementation for this.

Then i came up with a my own stored procedure ,

I have created my own variable - for clearing last 6 months data AGO_SIX_MONTH_DATE

You can use your own value.

[The solution is at below link -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945203/spring-batch-meta-data-tables-purging/51424692)

Spring Batch Meta-Data tables Purging

Comment: I omitted `select distinct JOB_INSTANCE_ID bulk collect into` and use `not exists` instead to cleanup `batch_job_instance`.

Comment: You haven't mentioned DB flavor. I suspect it is MSSQL. My queries differ in minor details. Like I doesn't join to `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` when delete based on `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION.START_TIME` though I do that later. It is because `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` is the most bloated table in our use.

Comment: well the DB here is Oracle , mostly you will find similar structure of batch tables across different databases , to clean up these tables , i have followed the meta data model provided by Spring  , you can check the model diagram here  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html